# How to write a for loop for 500 values of theta between 0 and 2pi

Tags: python

I am trying to write a for-loop for the 500 values of theta between 0 and 2pi using these formulas:

```
x = r cos(θ)
y = sin(3θ) −2 cos(2(θ + 0.2)) + 2 sin(7θ)
z = r sin(θ)**
```

This is what I have:

```
for i in range(500):
    x = r*np.cos(i)
    y = (np.sin(3*i)) - 2*np.cos(2*(i + 0.2)) + (2*np.sin(7*i))
    z = r*np.sin(i)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Could you clarify what issue(s) you're facing? Please edit a description of those issues into your post.

Comment: If you're trying to range theta between 0 and 2*pi, then I guess you need something like `theta = i * np.pi / 250`. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `numpy` anyway, you can get rid of `for` loops altogether, because `numpy` is designed to perform the same operation on a whole array of numbers:

```
thetas = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 500)
r = 1
x = r*np.cos(thetas)
y = (np.sin(3*thetas)) - 2*np.cos(2*(thetas + 0.2)) + (2*np.sin(7*thetas))
z = r*np.sin(thetas)
```

Here `thetas` variable will contain an array of 500 numbers between 0 and 2pi.
And next `x`, `y`, and `z` variables will also be arrays with 500 numbers, containing the values calculated with all the given thetas.

Comment: recommended to get rid of `for` loop because `numpy` is much faster (contiguous and smaller data). Also known as `Vectorization`.